# Initializing a Map with List inside

Tags: java

I need to use a Map with a List inside :

```
Map<String, List<String>> keyToGroup = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>();
```

I am getting compiler error on this line in eclipse.

The only working thing seem to be changing the inside List in the Map to ArrayList

```
Map<String, ArrayList<String>> keyToGroup = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>();
```

I had to change the signature of many interfaces' methods, but I still don't get it; why isn't the first definition work?

Isn't it the same, should not

```
Map<String, List<String>> keyToGroup
```

&

```
Map<String, ArrayList<String>>
```

be the same?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, they're not. Consider this:

```
Map<String, List<String>> keyToGroup = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>();
keyToGroup.put("foo", new LinkedList<String>());
```

The second line is fine, because a `LinkedList<String>` is a `List<String>` - but it's not logically fine in terms of adding it to a `HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>`, because a `LinkedList<String>` is *not* an `ArrayList<String>`.

To make it clearer:

```
Map<String, ArrayList<String>> map1 = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>();
Map<String, List<String>> map2 = map1; // This is invalid
map2.put("foo", new LinkedList<String>());
ArrayList<String> oops = map1.get("foo"); // Because this would be broken
```

This isn't just the case with collections as the type argument. It's even simpler to see with normal inheritance:

```
List<Banana> bunchOfBananas = new ArrayList<Banana>();
List<Fruit> fruitBowl = bunchOfBananas; // Invalid!
fruitBowl.add(new Apple());
Banana banana = bunchOfBananas.get(0);
```

Even though every banana is a fruit, so a "collection of bananas" is a "collection of fruit* in the sense of *fetching* them, not every fruit is a banana.

You can use [wildcard parameterized types](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/ParameterizedTypes.html#Topic4) to help in some cases, but it depends on exactly what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

No they are not. Generics are not **covariant** in Java.

If they are covariant you can logically put any type of `List` instead of `ArrayList` which defeats the purpose of having generics.

Consider reading Effective Java (2nd Edition) Chapter 5: Generics which has very good explanation of Generics.

Another good read is http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/JavaGenericsFAQ.html

Answer (score 0):

Ask yourself a question if you need particular list implementation in your Map or any List?
In case of particular implementation you can use your last example:

```
Map<String, ArrayList<String>> keyToGroup = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>();
```

In case of any list just use:

```
Map<String, List<String>> keyToGroup = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
keyToGroup.put("arraylist", new ArrayList<String());
keyToGroup.put("linkedlist", new LinkedList<String());
```

BTW the second option usually is better from design point of view so if you don't know exactly for now - try using second option first.

Comment: I like this approach, it is flexible; but my problem was that I need this variable as a method parameter, and I need to read the added values (out Parameter); so I don't think this would work because the List is not initiated yet.